# Procedure or function expects parameter '@OperatorName', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am getting some unexpected error,
I have two two methods one **is INSERTUPDATE & other is GETDATA**

```
for INSERT UPDATE SP is -- >> spInsert_WorkEntry
for GETDATA SP is       -- >> spGetWorkEntryData
```

for both the SP parameters are same as shown in the Image.

I am generating parameters dynamically. as shown in the **CreateParams**.
Creating parameter is same for both the methods for **INSERTUPDATE & GETDATA**.

Insert update method works fine & working as expected.

But when I tries to execute other method i.e.  **GETDATA** it is giving me error that **@OperatorName parameter is expected**.
First parameter is **@AutoID** that parameter is not giving error.
I have checked all the possible scenarios that can be cauing issue but now get anything.

```
public int InsertOrUpdate(WorkEntry t, string callingPage, string operation)
{ // Start the Insert Update Method
    IDbDataParameter[] param = null;
    int returnValue = 0;
    try
    {
        param = CreateParams(t, callingPage, operation);
        param[0].Value = t.AutoID;
        param[1].Value = t.OperatorName;
        param[2].Value = t.Date;
        param[3].Value = t.StartDate;
        param[4].Value = t.EndDate;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spInsert_WorkEntry";
        command.Parameters.AddRange(param);

        returnValue = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return returnValue;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return returnValue;
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        param = null;
    }
}// End the Insert Update Method
// Get-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public DataSet Get(WorkEntry t, string callingPage, string operation)
{ // Start the Insert Update Method
    IDbDataParameter[] param = null;
    DataSet returnValue = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        param = CreateParams(t, callingPage, operation);
        param[0].Value = t.AutoID;
        param[1].Value = t.OperatorName;
        param[2].Value = t.Date;
        param[3].Value = t.StartDate;
        param[4].Value = t.EndDate;

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spGetWorkEntryData";
        command.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        da.Fill(ds);

        sqlConnection.Close();
        return returnValue;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        param = null;
        command.Parameters.Clear();

    }
}// End the Insert Update Method
// Get End -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public IDbDataParameter[] CreateParams(WorkEntry workEntry, string CallingPage, string Operation)
{
    IDbDataParameter[] param = new IDbDataParameter[5];

    param[0] = new SqlParameter();
    param[0].DbType = DbType.Int32;
    param[0].Size = 50;
    param[0].ParameterName = "@AutoID";
    param[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    param[1] = new SqlParameter();
    param[1].DbType = DbType.String;
    param[1].Size = 50;
    param[1].ParameterName = "@OperatorName";
    param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    param[2] = new SqlParameter();
    param[2].DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    param[2].Size = 50;
    param[2].ParameterName = "@Date";
    param[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    param[3] = new SqlParameter();
    param[3].DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    param[3].Size = 50;
    param[3].ParameterName = "@StartDate";
    param[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    param[4] = new SqlParameter();
    param[4].DbType = DbType.DateTime;
    param[4].Size = 50;
    param[4].ParameterName = "@EndDate";
    param[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    return param;
}
```

Below is the image for SP

[image: GetData SP]

[image: Insert SP]

Comment: This most likely will not solve your issue, but `DbType.String` should be used for Unicode strings (i.e. for `nchar` and `nvarchar`), where for `varchar` you should use `DbType.AnsiString`. Also in C# code you have size set to 50, where in your procedure size is 100.

Comment: I have also tried by using chaging the datatype for the testing then also it was not working. I have make that as integer for checking so it was not working

Comment: Why are you passing Parameters for select SP?

Comment: @HardikParmar i guess you are right, but for select statement if you are not using `Where` clause then maybe passing parameters is unnecessary

Comment: Actually My parameters are generating automatically. so I need that parameter later on.

Comment: @dotnetom I have done what you have told me then also its not working. I have done nvarchar(50) for the SP parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move `command.Parameters.AddRange(param);` before `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);` statement

```
 SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
   command.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "spGetWorkEntryData";

        da.Fill(ds);
```

Also for select statement if you are not using `Where` clause then maybe passing parameters is unnecessary.

**Update**: I tested it and its working fine on my example

some changes which I made into your `Get` Method

```
public DataSet Get(string callingPage, string operation)
    { // Start the Insert Update Method

        // new instance of dataset and sqlcommand
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

        IDbDataParameter[] param = null;
        DataSet returnValue = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            param = CreateParams(callingPage, operation);
            param[0].Value = 1;
            param[1].Value = "";
            param[2].Value = DateTime.Now;
            param[3].Value = DateTime.Now;
            param[4].Value = DateTime.Now;

            // using connectin string property insted ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
            sqlConnection.Open();
            command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "spGetWorkEntryData";
            command.Parameters.AddRange(param);
            da.Fill(ds);

            sqlConnection.Close();
            return returnValue;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            param = null;
            command.Parameters.Clear();

        }
    }// End
```

My Demo Stored procedure

```
Create proc [dbo].[spGetWorkEntryData]
@autoId int,
@operatorName varchar(100),
@date datetime,
@startDate datetime,
@enddate datetime

as

begin
select * from dbo.tblBinaryUsers
end
```

**Result :**
[image]

Comment: yes your code is working I got the excet root cause why code was not behaving not as expected. Beacause when we pass the null value to parameter it not adds in the parameter list which we are passing the stored procedure. when i have pass some value to the parameter it was working as expected. thanks for your time & help. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @HardikParmar Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove all parameters from select query SP spGetWorkEntryData , it not need this , 
and  your sp will be

```
create proc spGetWorkEntryData 
as 
begin
select operatorname, date, startdate ,enddate from workentry
end
```

Comment: whats the new error are thrown , and also check db connection that you use the same db.

Comment: Procedure or function expects parameter '@OperatorName', which was not supplied

Comment: can share you call of this method

Comment: And also change the command for both Command1 for insert and Command2 for get method then try , because ambigious name may issue